# Does heating 3-phenylpropionic acid decarboxylate it?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, carbonyl-compounds

[image: This is the question]

Here, when P is reacted with $\ce{SOCl2}$ and then NaCN to give *3-phenylpropionitrile* and then hydrolysed to give *3-phenylpropionic acid*. Why shouldn't it further decarboxylate and dehydrogenate to give styrene instead of continuing with the reaction scheme ahead, as heating is also mentioned?

Answer key given says that **(B)** is the correct answer.

Comment: No, 3-phenylpropionic acid does not readily decarboxylate. The sulfuric acid protonates the carboxylic acid which loses water creating the R-C=O+ cation which elecrophilically adds to the aromatic ring.

Comment: My teacher told me that it would decarboxylate at 112°-113°C thus i asked the question

Comment: Your teacher is in error. Wikipedia quotes a boiling point of 280C for it  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenylpropanoic_acid

Comment: Thanks for clarification!